# How to pin the chrome extension automatically using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer, browser-automation

I am trying to automate the process of pinning a Chrome extension using Puppeteer. I want to be able to programmatically pin an extension without any manual intervention. I believe Puppeteer, a powerful browser automation tool, can help achieve this. However, I am unsure about the exact steps and code required to accomplish this task. Can someone guide me on how to automatically pin a Chrome extension using Puppeteer?

This is the basic code that I tried. I have installed the extensions automatically using puppeteer, but I want to complete the code to pin the extensions automatically

`index.js`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');

const { click,delay } = require('puppeteer-utilz');
const path = require('path');

const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const stealth = StealthPlugin();
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
stealth.enabledEvasions.delete('iframe.contentWindow');

require('dotenv').config();

const readline = require('readline')

(async () => {
    try {
        for (;;) {
            const email = await ask('Email: ');

            const extension1 = path.join(process.cwd(), 'extensions/adblocker');
            let options;

            options = {
                headless: false,
                args: [
                    `--disable-extensions-except=${extension1}`,
                    `--load-extension=${extension1}`,
                    "--start-maximized"
                ]
            };
                
            let browser = await puppeteer.launch(options)
            let page = (await browser.pages())[0]
        
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})()
```

Comment: I don't have time to research it more, but looks like it may be possible: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/208937173/how-do-i-pin-a-chrome-extension-to-the-toolbar?hl=en 
Also, I saw a comment from @wOxxOm: "Add ExtensionSettings policy for your extension id with toolbar_pin property set to force_pinned"

Comment: thanks, but that seems to be the manual action. is there any way to do it automatically?